# IndexedDB - initial transaction does not complete

Tags: indexeddb

I want to have a list of friends - three of them should appear in the list on page load. Initially I did it in `openRequest.onsucces` with the use of `addFriend` function - but then I received an error in console log saying that the key already exist. So I commented that out and I decided to add initial values to IndexedDB in openRequest.onupgradeneeded but I cannot make it work. The data is not added to indexedDB on payload at all.

The code is as follows:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    if ('indexedDB' in window) {
        let db;
        const submitButton = $('.submit');

        //indexedDB.open returns a request for a database becasue IndexedDB is asynchronous
        let openRequest = indexedDB.open('exerciseDB', 1);

        //only in 'onupgradeneeded' we can create object stores
        openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
            //set db variable to hold the database
            db = event.target.result;
            let friendsStore = db.createObjectStore('friends');

            friendsStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
                let transaction = db.transaction(['friends'], 'readwrite'),
                    store = transaction.objectStore('friends'),
                    friends = [{ name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@bob.com'}, { name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@bob.com'},
                    { name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@bob.com'}];

                    friends.forEach(friend => store.add(friend, name));
            }
        }

        //'onsuccess' fires after 'onupgradeneeded' completes and it also fires if we refresh the page and open the database again
        openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
            db = event.target.result;

            // addFriend(db, 'Bob', 'bob@bob.com');
            // addFriend(db, 'Jack', 'jack@jack.com');
            // addFriend(db, 'Pete', 'pete@pete.com');

            //once the database is ready display the friends we already have
            getAndDisplayFriends(db);
        }

        openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log('error', event.target.error);
        }

        function addFriend(db, name, email) {
            //start a database transaction
            let transaction = db.transaction(['friends'], 'readwrite');
            //get the friends object store
            let store = transaction.objectStore('friends');
            let friend = {name: name, email: email};
            store.add(friend, name); //name is the key

            transaction.oncomplete = function() { 
                getAndDisplayFriends(db); 
            }

            transaction.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log('error adding friend ' + event.target.error);
            }
        }

        function getAndDisplayFriends(db) {
            let transaction = db.transaction(['friends'], 'readonly');
            let store = transaction.objectStore('friends');
            let friendsList = $('.friends');

            //create a cursor request to get all items in the store, which we collect in allFriends array
            let req = store.openCursor();
            let allFriends = [];

            req.onsuccess = function(event) {
                let cursor = event.target.result;

                if (cursor != null) {
                    allFriends.push(cursor.value);
                    cursor.continue();
                } else {
                    //if we have a null cursor, it means we've gotten all the items in the store
                    displayFriends(allFriends, friendsList);
                }
            }

            req.onerror = function(event) {
                alert('error in cursor request ' + event.target.error);
            }
        }

        function displayFriends(friendsArray = [], list) {
            //empty the list before pulling friends from database - otherwise they will be displayed multiple times
            list.empty();
            friendsArray.forEach((friend) => {
                list.append(`<li>${friend.name} - ${friend.email}`);
            });
        }

        function getFriendData() {
            const friendName = $('#friend-name').val(),
                friendEmail = $('#friend-email').val();

            addFriend(db, friendName, friendEmail);
        }

        function bindUiEvents() {
            submitButton.on('click', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                getFriendData();
            });
        }

        bindUiEvents();
    }
}())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the add-friends operation to store the data in the database and complete before trying to query the database. It looks to me like you need to spend some time learning about asynchronous javascript.

However, learning how async code works can take a while and is quite challenging. So, to solve the problem for you quickly, albeit inelegantly and without really explaining how it works, I suggest you rewrite the code, something like this:

```js
function dothings() {
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
  openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction(...);
    var store = tx.objectStore(...);
    for (var friend of friends) {
      store.add(friend);
    }

    // and here is the solution to your problem, the trick is that we only start 
    // another transaction once the first one completes
    tx.oncomplete = function(event) {
      var tx2 = db.transaction(...);
      var store2 = tx2.objectStore(...);
      var request = store2.getAll();
      request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        var friends = event.target.result;
        for (var friend of friends) {
          addFriendToHTML(friend);
        }
      };
    };
  };
}
```

edit: i just read my answer again, not sure I helped enough. The problem lies in your original commented code. Here are some things that may help clarify:

1. You were starting a transaction per addFriend, when you could use one transaction for all of them.
2. You were calling `getAndDisplayFriends` before waiting for all of the `addFriend` calls to complete.
3. In your new code, it looks like you are only inserting on database upgrade in the onupgradeneeded handler, but you are not incrementing the version every single time you want to add friends, so you are never triggering any inserts.

You have a few options:

- go back and look at the example code i gave, it will work if you are really stuck, or
- change your code, write a function addFriends that adds all of your friends, and THEN calls a callback function when the transaction completes, and THEN only within that callback function, do the call `getAndDisplayFriends`
- if you are comfortable with using promises we can really clean up the code and the logic will become clearer and i can help you with that if you want

Comment: Thanks a lot. When debugging I saw that I do not completely understand the sequence of things happening. I will try to analyze and correct the code following your suggestions and I will come back to you if I do not manage.